# TikZ won't support HSB color model hsb in article document class

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, color, document-classes, article

I'm trying to use the wave color model in a tikz picture using the document class article.  When I do, I get the error message "Unsupported color model 'hsb'".  Consider the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{MyColor}{wave}{500}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{MyColor}{Hello}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[fill=MyColor, circle](1) at (0,0){};
\node[fill=red, circle](2) at (2,0){};
\node[fill={rgb:red,1;green,0;blue,1}, circle](3) at (4,0){};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This produces

[image]

with the error message written above.  Notice that the defined color MyColor works fine in text, but not in tikz.  Also notice that tikz does support the rgb color model.

If I change the document class to beamer, with the option xcolor={rgb}, then I get

[image]

If I try to add the option xcolor={rgb} to the document class article, the code won't compile.

Is there a work-around to being able to use the wave color model inside of a tikz picture using the article document class?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the `rgb` option as *package* option to `xcolor`:

```
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
```

or, passing it as a global option, to be picked up by `xcolor`, as in

```
\documentclass[rgb]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

seem to work both in `beamer` and in `article`. A little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{MyColor}{wave}{500}
\definecolor{MyColori}{wave}{450}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{MyColor}{Hello}

\textcolor{MyColori}{Hello}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[fill=MyColor, circle](1) at (0,0){};
\node[fill=red, circle](2) at (2,0){};
\node[fill={rgb:red,1;green,0;blue,1}, circle](3) at (4,0){};
\node[fill=MyColori, circle](1) at (6,0){};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Gonzalo, your answer solved my problem. I had a color definition in *hsb* such as, `\definecolor{mycolor}{hsb}{0,1,1}` and TikZ refused to accept the color `mycolor`. But adding this simple option `[rgb]` to the `xcolor` package, as you suggested, took away any errors. God bless you!