# Can I use \substitutecolormodel{hsb}{rgb} rather than \selectcolormodel{rgb} to draw PGF/TikZ paths with a hsb-defined colour series?

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, color, package-writing, compilation-error

Consider the following MNWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolorseries{xcolor g2}{hsb}{grad}[hsb]{.575,1,1}{.987,-.234,0}
\definecolorseries{xcolor s2}{hsb}{step}[hsb]{.575,1,1}{.11,-.05,0}
\resetcolorseries{xcolor g2}
\resetcolorseries{xcolor s2}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (b)  {% works
    \textcolor{xcolor g2!![6]}{colour 6}};
  
  % fails
  \path [draw=xcolor g2!!+] (b) -- +(0,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This fails to draw the `\path` with

```
! Package pgf Error: Unsupported color model `hsb'. Sorry.

See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.273   \path [draw=xcolor g2!!+] (d) -- +(0,-2);
```

There is a straightforward solution to this problem, implied by section 114.1.1 of the pgf/Ti*k*Z manual and illustrated in [Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230489/) and this is to load `xcolor` with option `rgb` or passing `rgb` to the package as a global option.

However, I'm using the colour series in a package and I don't want to force `rgb` on the user globally. So I think it would be better to use `\selectcolormodel{rgb}` within a local group.

```
\selectcolormodel{rgb}
% now works
\path [draw=xcolor g2!!+] (d) -- +(0,-2);
```

Because a user might mix a colour from the series with another colour using some other model, I would prefer to restrict the effect to the colour series itself. However, it wouldn't seem entirely unreasonable to apply it to any colour defined with `hsb`, even if that's not ideal. So

```
\substitutecolormodel{hsb}{rgb}
```

would seem the best of the obviously-available options. However, I can't get this to work. Even

```
\substitutecolormodel{hsb}{rgb}
\convertcolorsUtrue
```

has no effect. Nor does adding

```
\convertcolorsDtrue
```

make any difference. Nor does defining the colour series with the substitution active help. Only a wholesale switch to `rgb`, albeit temporary, avoids errors.

Is it possible to substitute `rgb` for `hsb` here without doing the same for other colour models, such as `cymk`?

Comment: @Sebastiano No worries. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Well the problem is that xcolor doesn't support stroke and fill colors. pgf has therefore its own backend commands for stroke and fill which write the correct literals and this backend doesn't support the hsb model.

You could try this, but I'm not sure if colors will be correct everywhere as the pgf low-level commands don't reset after a group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolorseries{xcolor g2}{hsb}{grad}[hsb]{.575,1,1}{.987,-.234,0}
\definecolorseries{xcolor s2}{hsb}{step}[hsb]{.575,1,1}{.11,-.05,0}
\resetcolorseries{xcolor g2}
\resetcolorseries{xcolor s2}

\makeatletter\ExplSyntaxOn
\def\pgfsys@color@hsb@fill#1#2#3{\color_fill:nn{hsb}{#1,#2,#3}}
\def\pgfsys@color@hsb@stroke#1#2#3{\color_stroke:nn{hsb}{#1,#2,#3}}

%example how to force cmyk:
\AddToHookWithArguments{cmd/selectcolormodel/before}
 {\tl_set:Nn\l_color_fixed_model_tl{#1}}
\selectcolormodel{cmyk}
\ExplSyntaxOff\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (b)  {% works
    \textcolor{xcolor g2!![6]}{colour 6}};
  
  % fails
  \path [draw=xcolor g2!!+] (b) -- +(0,-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does shading work? It seems as if that would involve filling.

Comment: @cfr shadings are special objects, they don't write literals for fill and stroke color into the streams.